# Why is DateTime.TryParseExact in C# is not working as expected

Tags: c#

When I try to run

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(employeeHireDate, "mm/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dDate);
```

C# is converting the DateTime to some other date that is 1/5/2015 where as im passing 05/05/2015.

Any help would be appreciated.

Following is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string employeeHireDate = "05/05/2015";         
    DateTime dDate;
    var isDateValid= DateTime.TryParseExact(employeeHireDate, "m/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dDate);

    if (!isDateValid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: m is minute M is month so MM for a two digit month, dd for days.

Comment: `DateTime.TryParseExact is not working`  Wrong.  It's doing exactly what you tell it to do.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew M is for months and mm is for minutes. Thanks for telling me. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lower-case `m` in a format string is **minutes**. You want an upper-case `M` for months. Five minutes, with no month value specified, means you end up with the first month of the year. You need this instead:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(employeeHireDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dDate);
```

Here's the reference:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Awesome, this fix helped. It's working now. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way where I can allow my code to accept both date formats that is, MM/dd/yyyy and M/d/yyyy?

Comment: Yes. One of the overloads is for an array of formats.

Comment: Awesome, its working, I did something like this.             var formatStrings = new string[] { "M/d/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy" };
            DateTime dDate;
            var isDateValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(employeeHireDate, formatStrings, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dDate);

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(employeeHireDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dDate);
```

instead, with captial `"MM"`. `mm` is for minutes, `MM` is for months (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)).

Answer (score 2):

when you use TryParseExact, it must be the exact format. "05/05/2015" matches "MM/dd/yyyy" not "m/d/yyyy".

it should be:

```
    var isDateValid= DateTime.TryParseExact(employeeHireDate, "MM/dd/yyyy",

 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dDate);
```

also note that "mm" is for `Minute` and you should use "MM" for month.